# I would like to copy the animation to another character using Auto Rig Pro

Tags: animation

I would like to copy the animation to another character using Auto Rig Pro

I need to apply the animation to a total of 5 characters, but I can't find the Armature, probably because I rigged it using Auto Rig Pro.

You can use Auto Rig Pro's Remap feature to copy the animation to another character, but the location will be the same, so you'll have to shift the x axis frame by frame, which is very annoying. (30frame * 5character)

---

In the method of selecting, copying and pasting the keyframe of timeline,
The error message "No selected F-Curves t opaste into" was displayed.

With the Shortcut "L" key method, pressing the L key did not display the menu.

---

I would like to copy a running animation like the central character to another character in a horizontal row.(please see image)

I'm using Blender 2.93
[image]

Comment: the location will be the same if you've keyframed the armature object itself, but you could exclude all the keyframes related to the armature (if it is not used to make the object move in the 3D scene) or you could parent each armature to an empty?

Comment: Ohh It works!! I can parent armature to an empty!! And Samurai Sword is also can parent to an empty!! 
I would like to share a image which they are animation!
https://ibb.co/rpymqXj
Thank you so much!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Delete all the keyframes related to the armature object itself, or parent each armature object to an empty.